# Reading file into structure (c++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector

I am very very new to C++, and I would like to read a text file into a structure. The text file has a double on the first line, and the lines after that exist as gift names (wishes). I created a struct, Wishlist, that exist as a double and a vector of wishes. So I did the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Gift
{
    double price;
    string name;
};

typedef vector<Gift> Giftstore;
typedef vector<string> Wishes;


int size(Giftstore& g) {return static_cast<int>(g.size());}

int size(Wishes& w) {return static_cast<int>(w.size());}


struct Wishlist
{
    double budget;
    Wishes wishes;
};


void reading_wishlist(ifstream& file, Wishlist& wish_list)
{
    if (file)
    {
        double money;

        file>>money;
        wish_list.budget<<money;
    }

    while(file)
    {
        string name;
        getline(file, name)
        wish_list.wishes.push_back(name);
    }

    file.close();
};


void print(Wishlist wish_list)
{
    cout<<"Budget: "<<wish_list.budget<<endl;
    cout<<"Wishes: "<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<size(wish_list.wishes()); i++)
    {
        cout<<wish_list.wishes[i]<<endl;
    }
};

int main () {

  ifstream file;
  string filename;
  cout<<"Give a wishlist file: ";
  cin>>filename;

  file.open(filename)
  reading_wishlist(filename, wish_list);
  print(wish_list)

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, while trying to build and run this, I again won some error prizes! The first one, is saying: (in reference to: wish_list.budget<

Invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary operator<<

What does this mean? Do I have to redefine the operator << ?  Or can I read the double as a Cstring and then change it to double?

What is the best way to deal with this? Better: how to read different types from a file? Since I also have to read a file into a structure, Giftstore, where the text file will consist of a double and a gift name on each line.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. You are missing some critical information, such as the file name and line number where the error occurs. Also please indicate which line of code gives the error.

Comment: Well just looking, you missed some end-of-line semicolons. Lines 43, 69, 71

Comment: "What does this mean?" - it means that what you typed doesn't make sense. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Line 37; you should do `wish_list.budget = money;` instead of `wish_list.budget<<money;`

Comment: Line 68; should be `Wishlist wish_list;` to actually have an object of type `Wishlist` to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error arises from this line in the `reading_wishlist` function

`wish_list.budget<<money;`

You cannot use `<<` operator with a double as the left hand side (here WishList::budget).
Do you mean

`wish_list.budget = money;`

Comment: You are welcome! You can mark it as the answer if it fixed all your issues. Also, if you rename `void reading_wishlist` to `ifstream& operator>>` and return `file` instead of closing it, you can just write `file>>wish_list` if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! Only the double that is put into the structure is 1.6965e+260 and in the text file it is 50.00 and there is nothing in the vector wishes :-S

Comment: @Lola you mean if you change it to `operator>>`?

Comment: wait a minute... it even does this with non-existing files...

Comment: Makes Sense for non existing files. What you are getting is non initialized double and vector- you never enter the `if(file)` or `while(file)` Btw you might want to check the state of the `file` after `cin` as well, because the last thing you will get from `cin` will be End-Of-File

Comment: Something goes very wrong with my use of ifstream.. cause I can't use file.open()

Comment: I get this error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)'|

Comment: try `filename.c_str()`? This is a compile error, how was it working until now?

Comment: @Lola How about checking the result of the file open. Or perhaps moving the actual decl *past* the filename request, then openning like `ifstream file(filename); if (file) { ..code here.. }`